# How can I always show the hover title in expose when using compiz?

Tags: compiz, customization

I have expose mode on.  When I use expose mode I get the zoom out showing all my windows.  This is fine. However, when I hover my mouse over one of those windows I get a title bar of what that window is.  Is there a way to set it show it always shows the hovering title on all windows and not just when I hover over it?  I have the compiz settings manager installed but didn't see any options in there to turn it on.

Comment: Compiz calls that feature Scale (it works like Mac OSX's Expose). There's another feature called Expo that shows all workspaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Compiz Settings Manager and look for *Scale Addons* (confusingly in the Utility section, not with the regular *Scale* plugin under Window Management). From there, click on the *Appearance* tab and open the *Window Title* section. You'll find a drop-down menu for the *Window Title Display*, which you can change to *All Windows*.

I believe you might also need to have the package "compiz-plugins-extra".

In addition, as pydave mentions below, make sure that the *Text Plugin* (in the Image Loading Section), is enabled.

Comment: There wasn't a title option for me but a show icon overlay, which worked out even better.  Thanks!

Comment: Something that's easy to forget is that for Window Title Display to work, you also need to enable the Text plugin (under Image Loading).